# How to delete a character from href attribute using JavaScript or JQuery after DOM loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to use some links with a special character in their 'href' values...

For example the link is: `www.my*blog.com`

and when document is loaded the '*' will be deleted by JavaScript or jQuery Function.

I used two functions:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var i=0,j='',val='';
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i;i<=list.length;i++)
    {
      j=list[i].getAttribute("href");
      val = j.replace('*','');
      list[i].setAttribute('href',val);
    }

}, false);
```

and in jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var i=0,j='',val='';
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i;i<=list.length;i++)
    {
      j=$(list[i]).attr('href');
      val = j.replace('*','');
      $(list[i]).attr('href',val);
    }
});
```

But this functions don't work properly in some cases...

Comment: What are the cases and what is happening then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("a[href*='*']").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("href", jQuery(this).attr("href").replace(/\*/g, ""));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work good...But can you explain why my functions don't work in some cases? (something like using old JQuery?)

Comment: Probably because of this:
1. You should use this:
  for(i;i<list.length;i++)
instead of this:
  for(i;i<=list.length;i++)
2. Javascript replace() function replaces only first substring by default.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected the loop condition as it is executing the loop one extra iteration:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var i=0,j='',val='';
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i;i<list.length;i++)//for(i;i<=list.length;i++)
    {
      j=$(list[i]).attr('href');
      val = j.replace('*','');
      $(list[i]).attr('href',val);
    }
});
```